# How to make a single jButton activate a whole row of jButtons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Currently i am able to activate all my jButtons upon clicking them 
but my professor demands that i have click only 1 jButtons to activate the last two rows jButtons.

e.g 
If "11" jButton is pressed, the whole row of jButtons should be activated and displays "SUMMARY" on the last second row and "12", "15" ...."32" on the last row.

Please use the OUTPUT image and my code for reference. Thanks in advance!

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWwua.png)

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

public class A3 extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
private final JButton [] jbArray;
private final JButton [] jbArray2;
private final JButton [] jbArray3;
private final GridLayout gl;

public A3 ()
{
   super ("Good Luck To You");
   gl = new GridLayout (9,7);
   setLayout(gl);

   jbArray = new JButton [49];
   jbArray2 = new JButton [7];
   jbArray3 = new JButton [7];

   for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++)
   {
       jbArray [i] = new JButton ("SP");
       add(jbArray[i]);
       jbArray[i].addActionListener(this);
   }

    String s = "SUMMARY";
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
        jbArray2 [j] = new JButton (String.valueOf(s.charAt(j)));
        add (jbArray2[j]);
        jbArray2[j].addActionListener(this);
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < 7; l++)
   {
       jbArray3 [l] = new JButton ("SP");
       add(jbArray3[l]);
       jbArray3[l].addActionListener(this);
   }

   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   setSize(700,700);
   setVisible(true);    

 }

 static List <Integer> aList;
 public static void forList ()
 {
   int num [] = new int [49];

   for (int j = 0; j < num.length; j++)
        num[j] = j + 1;

   aList = Arrays.stream (num)
                 .boxed ()
                 .collect (Collectors.toList());

    Collections.shuffle(aList);
 }

 static List <Integer> rList;
 public static void forRandom()
 {
   int r [] = new int [7];

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        r [i] = (int)(Math.random() * 49);

    rList = Arrays.stream(r)
                 .boxed()
                 .distinct()
                 .sorted()
                 .collect (Collectors.toList());

 }

 @Override
 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
 {
   String first = String.valueOf(rList.get(0));

   int n = 0;  
   {
        for (JButton k : jbArray)
        {

            if (e.getSource() == k)
            {
                k.setText(String.valueOf(aList.get(n)));
                k.getText();

                //Winning prize
                for ( int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                {   
                    String rFirst = String.valueOf(rList.get(i));
                    if(k.getText().equals(rFirst))
                    {
                        k.setBackground (Color.YELLOW);
                        k.setFont(new Font ("Serif", Font.BOLD, 19));
                    }
                }

                //Top prize
                if (k.getText().equals(first))
                {
                    k.setBackground (Color.GREEN);
                    k.setFont (new Font ("Italic", Font.BOLD, 22));
                }
            }
            ++n;
        }   
   }

   int a = 0;
   {
        for (JButton p : jbArray3)
        {
            if (e.getSource() == p)
            {
                p.setText(String.valueOf(rList.get(a)));
                p.setBackground (Color.YELLOW);
                p.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                p.setFont(new Font ("Serif", Font.BOLD, 19));
            }  
            ++a;

            if (p.getText().equals(first))
            {
                p.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }

            for (JButton m : jbArray2)
            {
                if (e.getSource() == m)
                {
                    m.setForeground(Color.RED);
                    m.setFont (new Font ("Serif", Font.BOLD, 19));
                }
            }
        }
   }
  }

  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
     A3 a3 = new A3 ();
     forList ();
     forRandom();  
  }

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for these kind of request. This is too long and not focusing on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, with a bit of guess work, basically if you tap the "winning" button, this will highlight the last row of buttons with all the values in `rList`.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<String> rList = new ArrayList<>(7);
        private List<JButton> summary = new ArrayList<>(7);

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 7));

            List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(7 * 7);
            for (int index = 0; index < 7 * 7; index++) {
                values.add(Integer.toString(index + 1));
            }

            Collections.shuffle(values);
            rList.addAll(values.subList(0, 7));
            Collections.shuffle(values);

            System.out.println(rList);

            for (String value : values) {
                JButton btn = makeButton(value);
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionHandler(btn));
                add(btn);
            }

            String text = "SUMMARY";
            for (String value : text.split("")) {
                add(makeButton(value));
            }
            for (int index = 0; index < 7; index++) {
                JButton btn = makeButton("");
                summary.add(btn);
                add(btn);
            }
        }

        public JButton makeButton(String text) {
            JButton btn = new JButton(text);
            btn.setFocusPainted(false);
            btn.setOpaque(true);
            btn.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY), new EmptyBorder(4, 8, 4, 8)));
            return btn;
        }

        public class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {

            private JButton button;

            public ActionHandler(JButton button) {
                this.button = button;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String first = rList.get(0);
                String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
                JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
                System.out.println("cmd = " + cmd);
                System.out.println("first = " + first);
                if (cmd.equals(first)) {
                    btn.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    for (int index = 0; index < rList.size(); index++) {
                        JButton b = summary.get(index);
                        String text = rList.get(index);
                        b.setText(text);
                        if (index == 0) {
                            b.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                        } else {
                            b.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (rList.contains(cmd)) {
                    btn.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

If, instead, you really need to have selected all the "other values" first, then you will need to maintain a count of "successful" matches and compare that when the "winning" values is clicked.

Comment: [help vampire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145348/how-to-make-selected-jbuttons-change-font-and-color?noredirect=1)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No arguments from me - but they're not going to like my answer because "it doesn't fit their implementation", which they've not provided :/, but maybe it might help someone else

Comment: Thanks but i can't run your code. I kept getting error on line 23 'The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (Test)' and line 31 'The nested type Test cannot hide an enclosing type'

Comment: @C.J.W Copy and Past my AS IS, into it's own project. Test it, see how it works. Once you understand what it's trying to do, THEN you can try modifying your own code to use the same principles.  `Test` is NOT a `Component` - it's a stand along object intended to provide a entry point into the example

Comment: @MadProgrammer Java 8, sorry about that. I have uploaded my entire code. Hope you can find out the problem for me. Thanks

Comment: @MadProgrammer I created a Test class and tried to run it but i kept getting those 2 errors.

Comment: @C.J.W Well, based on you error, you're trying to add `Test` to container - in my example, `Test` is the "main" class, it doesn't need to be added to anything

Comment: @MadProgrammer I created a new java project and added only Test class inside

Comment: @C.J.W :/ I've updated the example